# Get iterator object from inside the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the iteration object from the loop. I want
to avoid storing it in another variable and accessing it.
Is there a better way to do it, something like get_current_iterator()?

```py
        for idx, number in enumerate(range(1, 10)):
            # need to refer to enum object for use with
            # next()
```

Comment: No, there isn't. The normal way would be to do something like `en = enumerate(range(1, 10)); for i, e in en: ...`

Comment: You can pull the iter out via `e = iter(enumerate(range(1, 10)))` before the loop then do `for idx, number in e` then you can reference `e` outside of the loop but I don't know the full scope of your problem so I can't provide more than that.

Comment: Possible solution for Python 3.8: `for idx, number in (en := enumerate(range(1,10))):`

Comment: @chepner that's beautiful.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse beauty is in the eye of the beholder. The fights around that [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) were pretty much what drove Guido to step down as BDFL

Comment: You have to be careful, too, since `next(en)` in the loop could raise a `StopIteration` that the `for` loop won't catch for you.

Comment: @roganjosh kind of off-topic of the subject of the question, but do you have any resources you could link about how that discussion happened? I'm interested in learning more about the design choices involved.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Check the [python-ideas mailing list archive](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/). It was a long, wearisome debate.

Comment: @chepner but that doesn't really avoid storing it in another variable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agreed, but as that isn't possible, it's the next "lightest" solution, syntactically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

```
for idx, number, en in iter(lambda en=enumerate(range(1, 10)): (*next(en), en), 0):
    print(en, idx, number)
```

Prints:

```
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 0 1
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 1 2
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 2 3
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 3 4
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 4 5
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 5 6
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 6 7
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 7 8
<enumerate object at 0x7f74a11b7a68> 8 9
```

Comment: this also simply stores it in a variable to access it. This is just a very convoluted way of doing `en = enumerate(range(1, 10))` before the loop.